# Twitter API: Separate read and read/write tokens

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

On my site users should be able to authenticate using their twitter account. Another optional feature is, that users should be able to have tweets sent in their name on certain events. 
For this I've setup the twitter application to be read & write.

My problem now is, when a user is using twitter to authenticate, then he is automatically also granting read/write permissions. But I'd like to leave it up to the user to decide at a later stage if he trusts me enough, to grant me this permission..

I can't find any setting/parameter in the api which would allow this split. The only solution I can currently see, is splitting the twitter app into two: One read-only app for authentication and one read-write app for tweeting etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send users to `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=xyz` and add a parameter of `oauth_access_type` with a value of `read`. That should restrict that particular user to read only permissions.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-development-talk/1P765h9ecBk